# Android colors aren't reflected properly in emulator or device

Tags: android, colors

I'm trying to set the background of a RelativeLayout to a particular color.  However, the color that's being displayed by the emulator and by the device is off by quite a bit.

For example,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#e1e5e8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="85px">
```

`#e1e5e8` is a nice silvery color.

However, when I view the that layout in the emulator, the color I get back (using xScope on Snow Leopard to get the pixel values) is `#e7e7ef`, which looks a bit purpley.

Looking at the view on the G1 also looks a bit off from what I want.  If I take a screenshot of the G1 using the debugger and examine the pixels, they too are `#e7e7ef`.

What gives?  It seems like it must be more than simply a gamma issue, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the monitor on your Mac and device's display are different it's actually expected that colors will be slightly off. Since I don't know the way to calibrate your phone I say you can try to calibrate display on your Mac to make it look similar to the device. Then, of course G1 display and MyTouch display and any other display will be different too so I'm wondering if you even need to bother